# Check login without refreshing

Tags: python, django, ajax

how I can modify my code that be check login&password without refreshing? Ajax call function in django to check login and password then send .json with result. Next one I want display error in js if result is failed or play animation if it's true.

```
js code:

       function CheckBeforeSend()
{
  var LoginInput = document.getElementById('flogin');
  if(LoginInput.value.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+['.']+[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+$/) == null)
  {
    if(document.getElementById('Windows').childElementCount > 2)
    {
      document.getElementById('Windows').children[0].remove();
    }
    AddPicture("paperJsConn");
  } 
  else
  {
    document.getElementById("button").type = "submit";
    $.ajax({                                                                                                                           
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/',
      data: $('#login_form').serialize(), 
      type: "POST",
      async:false,
      success: function(response) {
        var CheckingCorrect = response['result'];
        //if checkingcorrect play func animation.
      },
      error: function(error){
        alert('No Connection!');
      }
    });
  }
}
$('#login_form').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post('view-url', $(this).serialize());
}); // this event dont work.
```

views.py:

```
def Logget(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    login = request.POST.get('flogin')
    response_data = {}
    response_data['result'] = 'Failed'
    lengthBase = UsersLog.objects.count()
    for i in range(lengthBase):
        if login == str(UsersLog.objects.get(id=i+1)): 
            password = request.POST.get('lpass', False)
            if str(password) == str(UsersLog.objects.get(id=i+1).password):
                response_data['result'] = 'Succes'
                break
    return JsonResponse(response_data)
  return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Comment: Observation,  your views.py has indentation issue starting at line 2.   this might be cut paste issue for putting code here.   if not you need to indent the body of the function one more indentation level starting at line 2

Comment: This is a bad paste